# Cast pointer to union to known base class of unknown active member

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, unions

Suppose I have a union and I know the active member derives from some (non-standard layout) base class, but I don't know which specific member is active. Is it legal to cast a pointer to that union, via `void *`, to a pointer to the base class, then use that base pointer?

For example, is this (which does compile with `g++ 11.3.0` with `-std=c++23`) legitimate?

```cpp
class base { public: virtual bool foo() = 0; };

class derived_1 : public base { bool foo() override { return true; }; };

class derived_2 : public base { bool foo() override { return false; }; };

union some_base {
  derived_1 x;
  derived_2 y;

  bool foo() {
    return static_cast<base *>(static_cast<void *>(this))->foo();
  };
};
```

Comment: A prvalue of type pointer to void (possibly cv-qualified) can be converted to pointer to any object type... if the original pointer value points to an object a, and there is an object b of the target type (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible (as defined below) with a, the result is a pointer to b.

Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if... one is a union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object, or... there exists an object c such that a and c are pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ah sorry, I'll update with a virtual function in `base` as that's closer to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Give `derived_1` a nonstatic data member to have a non-trivial situation to deal with.

Comment: For this to work, `some_base*` and `base*` need to be pointer-interconvertible. `some_base*` is interconvertible with `derived_1*` and `derived_2*` because `union` gives that guarantee. However since `base` is not a standard layout type which I believe means `base*` isn't not pointer-interconvertible with pointers to types that derived from it.

Comment: Casting through `void*` is unnecessarily convoluted. There is an easier way to spell that: `reinterpret_cast<base *>(this)`

Comment: @Spencer Why would that matter? Isn't the question whether the base class is laid out in the same way at the same address?

Comment: @eeroika In other words, it's like covering up the warning light with black electrical tape.

Comment: Practically speaking, you wish to assume that `base` is located at offset zero within both `dervied_1` and `derived_2`. This is not guaranteed; it could be at different offsets, at least one of which could be non-zero.

Comment: You might be able to skirt @IgorTandetnik 's point because `derived_1` and `derived_2` are declared identically. You cannot do that in general. So it would be a better example to have those two classes just a little different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The union object that `this` points to is pointer-interconvertible with the active `derived_1` or `derived_2`, but it is not pointer-interconvertible with the base class subobject of either. Pointer-interconvertibility between base and derived classes applies only to standard layout classes.

Therefore the cast will not result in a pointer to the base class subobject and the member access will have undefined behavior as the actual type of the pointed-to object is not similar to that of the expression.

The layout of the classes is not relevant to this. It is more similar to an aliasing violation. However, even regarding layout, there is nothing requiring the implementation to place the `Base` subobject at zero offset (or at equal offsets at all) into `derived_1` and `derived_2`.

The ABI specification will make a determination regarding the last point though. Then assuming that the layout is appropriate, it may very well work in practice. I am not sure whether or to what degree compilers use this aliasing-type violation for optimization in practice.